# Finding residue of composite function.

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion, residue-calculus, laurent-series

Let $f$ be analytic at $z_0\in\Bbb{C}$ and $g$ have a simple pole at $z_0$. Find $\operatorname{Res}(f(g(z_0)),z_0)$.

scratchwork (Would like big hints. I don't usually like asking for the full answer, but I have no choice this time.):

If $g$ has a simple pole at $z_0$ with residue $A$, then
\begin{align}
\operatorname{Res}(g(z),z_0)=\lim_{z\to z_0}(z-z_0)g(z)=\lim_{z\to z_0}(z-z_0)\frac{h(z)}{z-z_0}=\lim_{z\to z_0}h(z)=A \quad \text{, for some function h(z).}
\end{align}
Since $f$ is analytic at $z_0\in\Bbb{C}$, then it has taylor series representation, say $f(z)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(k)}(z_0)}{k!}(z-z_0)^k$.

Original problem statement(verbatim):
Let $f$ be analytic at $z=z_0$. calculate $\operatorname{Res}(fg,z_0)$, if

- (a) $g$ has a simple pole with residue $A$ at z=z_0.
- (b) $g$ has a    pole of order $k$ and principal part given by

\begin{align}
\frac{a_{-1}}{z-z_0}+\frac{a_{-2}}{(z-z_0)^2}+\cdots +\frac{a_{-k}}{(z-z_0)^k}
\end{align}

Comment: There is something wrong with the way the question is stated. The fact that $f$ is analytic at $z_0$ is of no use because we are interested in $f(g(z))$ for $z$ neat $z_0$.

Comment: Hold on. I'll upload a picture. thank you guys!

Comment: Don't upload a picture! Use MathJax.

Comment: Sorry I'll redo it.

Comment: You are reading the product $fg$ as $f\circ g$. @TheLastCipher

Comment: As stated it is the product of functions not the composite function.

Comment: Ohh darnnn it!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is $f(z_0)\operatorname{res}\bigl(g(z),z_0\bigr)$, since$$\lim_{z\to z_0}(z-z_0)f(z)g(z)=\lim_{z\to z_0}f(z)\times\lim_{z\to z_0}(z-z_0)g(z)=f(z_0)\operatorname{res}\bigl(g(z),z_0\bigr).$$

---

For the second part, note that if$$f(z)=a_0+a_1(z-z_0)+a_2(z-z_0)^2+\cdots$$and\begin{align}g(z)&=\frac{b_{-k}}{(z-z_0)^k}+\frac{b_{-k+1}}{(z-z_0)^{k-1}}+\cdots\\&=\frac1{(z-z_0)^k}\left(b_{-k}+b_{-k+1}(z-z_0)+\cdots\right),\end{align}then $(z-z_0)^{k-1}$ in$$\left(a_0+a_1(z-z_0)+a_2(z-z_0)^2+\cdots\right)\times\left(b_{-k}+b_{-k+1}(z-z_0)+\cdots\right),$$which is $a_0b_{-1}+a_1b_{-2}+\cdots+a_{k-1}b_{-k}$.

Comment: I agree. thanks!!

Comment: As for part (b), I am stuck with $\operatorname{Res}(fg,z_0)=\frac{1}{(k-1)!}\lim_{z \to z_0}\frac{d^{k-1}}{dz^{k-1}}[(z-z_0)^{k}fg]=\frac{1}{(k-1)!}\lim_{z\to z_0}\frac{d^{k-1}}{dz^{k-1}}[f(z)h(z)]$ such that $g(z)=h(z)/(z-z_0)^k$ and the fact that $\frac{d^{k-1}}{dz^{k-1}}[h(z)]=(k-1)!a_{-1}+\cdots$.

Comment: I've edited my answer.

Comment: Wow. How did you deduce the coefficient so quickly by simple expansion?

Comment: I computed the product. It's like multiplying polynomials.